# How does angular microfrontend can set the cookie in the shell application?

Tags: angular, cookies, webpack-5, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I am exposing a shared widget (ex: calendar widget) as a micro frontend that can be consumed across multiple applications in our organization. The consumed application loads our micro frontend on demand and after it gets loaded, as micro frontend, we don't have any way to communicate with the consuming application. I would like to set a cookie or localstorgage on the consumed application end, how can I set a cookie or localstorage variable from our shared widget (microfronetned) to the consumed application. Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

you can triger event in ngOnInit hook for shared app and cache the event in shell right?